# Short story; intelligent VD germ battles antibodies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was told from the viewpoint of various germs and antibodies in the hosts bloodstream.

From some unremembered SF anthology in the UK, I read it approximately 8 years ago.

The 'protagonist germ' battles against other types of germ, always winning.
He witnesses a battle between some antibodies and some invasive germs, he sees the antibodies are losing so hurls himself into battle on their side, he's such a ferocious fighter that the antibodies prevail and rout the invaders.

They gather around to thank him profusely for him help and he does like an "aw shucks" modesty thing.

The antibodies leader then politely asks his species and he proudly says Syphilis (maybe Gonorrhoea!) and they act all shocked and then rush him while he voices his protests at their ingratitude.

I can't recall if he then gets ripped up or if he manages to implant in the cell walls.

Comment: How long ago, where...

Comment: This sounds like so much fun to read that you know your audience members will want to read it. 
Do you remember anything else about the anthology or the stories -- were they all new stories, like best SF of a year after 2010, or from all time periods including Golden Age? Was the book itself new, or older? Was it British authors only, or published in the UK (i.e., not simply read in the UK)? Was there any theme to the anthology? Instead of a Year's Best SF, maybe themes like "War in other worlds" or "Life on other size scales"?

Comment: I *think* it was mainly American authors